# How to print to textarea

Tags: netbeans, jframe

Im pretty new to this programming so forgive me if i make any mistakes.
Im making a little program with NetBeans, only now i have to add something which i really dont know how to do.

I've made a little program with which you can calculate your interest. 
You have three jTextFields:

1. Your starting amount of money.
2. The percentage of interest you're dealing with.
3. The amount of years you want to calculate.

So further i have a jButton which contains the most of my code.

```
    double inputNumberInterest = Double.parseDouble(interest.getText());
    double inputNumberMoney = Double.parseDouble(money.getText());
    int inputNumberYears = Integer.parseInt(years.getText());
    DecimalFormat decimaal = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");

    double result = inputNumberMoney * Math.pow(inputNumberInterest / 100 + 1,    inputNumberYears);

    this.reply.setText("" + decimaal.format(result);
```

So this code prints the end result of the calculation.
Now what my question is, I want to years in between to be printed also in a textArea. For example the user of this program enters 5, as years of interest. I want the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th to be printed in a textArea. And the 5th year as it is now printed in a jTextField as i already have.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: You're missing a `)` in your last line

Comment: And is there a problem you are facing with your code?

Comment: No, my part of code is working just fine. I only need a piece of code how to print the amount of the years in between of the last year in a textArea.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. But try using `.append()` instead of `setText()`. Maybe that's what you are trying to do??

Comment: Can you explain how i need to use that because i cant find anything about it.

Comment: `this.reply.append("" + decimaal.format(result));`